# How to recover file system (ext4) on raid5?

Tags: filesystems, mdadm, raid5, ext4

I have an ext4 file system on a raid5 array, `/dev/md0` built from mdadm.

I found it wasn't mounted after I reboot once. And I ran a `fcsk` on it but get a superblock error.

So I was going to run `mke2fs -n /dev/md0` to get the information of backup superblock. But I ran `mke2fs /dev/md0` by mistake. I pressed Ctrl-C while the first time I was asked for inputing something about journal. But I still remember it was said that inode table was written.

After that, I ran `mke2fs -S /dev/md0` to generate the superblock only again since I couldn't recover it from backups.

Now, the superblock problem disappeared, but fsck want to fix tons of inode problems. I answered yes for some of them and pressed Ctrl-C when I realized that it seems trying to fix the inode to a fresh new inode table.

Is it still possible to get all my data back?
If yes, how?

---

Here is the raid information:

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Jun 27 18:02:54 2022
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 7813707776 (7451.73 GiB 8001.24 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906853888 (3725.87 GiB 4000.62 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Mon Jun 27 20:20:25 2022
             State : clean, degraded, recovering
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 64K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 2% complete

              Name : plq-pi:0  (local to host plq-pi)
              UUID : a2250592:81ebb835:4646cf4f:64feea42
            Events : 854

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       3     254        0        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/dm-0

$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 dm-0[3] sdb1[1] sdc1[0]
      7813707776 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.0% (79757168/3906853888) finish=6664.4min speed=9570K/sec
      bitmap: 0/30 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

And the `/dev/dm-0` is a lvm constructed by two disks.

The commands I executed:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/md0
fsck from util-linux 2.33.1
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/md0

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>


$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Creating filesystem with 1835008000 4k blocks and 229376000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: cca2e089-18bf-4d19-a5c2-077b47304fd2
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): ^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C

$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/md0
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Creating filesystem with 1835008000 4k blocks and 229376000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 722ca4ca-1cf7-4860-baff-91a019258b3f
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

$ sudo e2fsck -b 1934917632 /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
e2fsck: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/md0

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>


$ sudo e2fsck /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
/dev/md0 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 1 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Root inode is not a directory.  Clear<y>? yes
Inode 17 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 33 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 49 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 65 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 81 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 97 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 113 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes
yyyyyyInode 129 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes
Inode 145 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes
Inode 161 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear ('a' enables 'yes' to all) <y>? yes
Inode 177 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 193 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 209 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes
Inode 225 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear<y>? yes to all
Inode 497 has EXTENTS_FL flag set on filesystem without extents support.
Clear? yes
... more these ...


Inode 4840 is in use, but has dtime set.  Fix? yes

Inode 4840 has a extra size (6436) which is invalid
Fix? yes

Timestamp(s) on inode 4840 beyond 2310-04-04 are likely pre-1970.
Fix? yes

^CInode 4840 has a bad extended attribute block 1879399463.  Clear? yes

/dev/md0: e2fsck canceled.

/dev/md0: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/md0: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


$ sudo e2fsck -f /dev/md0
e2fsck 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>? yes
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Root inode is not a directory.  Clear<y>?
/dev/md0: e2fsck canceled.

/dev/md0: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/md0: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********
```

Comment: I don't see much chances for recovery of the filesystem. Since you recreated an ext4 filesystem the superblock backups have been written to the same locations as before, overwriting all backups of the superblock in the process. I'd just restore the backups.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider As you see, I tried some of the backups, but none worked. That's why I recreated the superblock. But I think the current problem is the inodes, I guess, there may be a hope if I could restore the inode table...